# Adding rows to a Dataframe to unify the length of groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, autofill

I would like to add element to specific groups in a Pandas DataFrame in a selective way. In particular, I would like to add zeros so that all groups have the same number of elements. The following is a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1], [2,2], [1,3], [2,4], [2,5]], columns=['key', 'value'])
df
   key  value
0    1      1
1    2      2
2    1      3
3    2      4
4    2      5
```

I would like to have the same number of elements per group (where grouping is by the `key` column). The group 2 has the most elements: three elements. However, the group 1 has only two elements so a zeros should be added as follows:

```
   key  value
0    1      1
1    2      2
2    1      3
3    2      4
4    2      5
5    1      0
```

Note that the index does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new level of `MultiIndex` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then add missing values by `unstack/stack` or `reindex`:

```
df = (df.set_index(['key', df.groupby('key').cumcount()])['value']
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .reset_index(name='value'))
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = df.set_index(['key', df.groupby('key').cumcount()]) 
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names = df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
   key  value
0    1      1
1    1      3
2    1      0
3    2      2
4    2      4
5    2      5
```

If is important order of values:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['key', df.groupby('key').cumcount()]) 

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels, names = df1.index.names)
#get appended values
miss = mux.difference(df1.index).get_level_values(0)

#create helper df and add 0 to all columns of original df
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key':miss}).reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=0)
#append to original df
df = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)

print (df)
   key  value
0    1      1
1    2      2
2    1      3
3    2      4
4    2      5
5    1      0
```